# Implent smart app banner similar Amazon

Tags: javascript, smartbanner

I would like to implement a smartbanner similar Amazon in Android.

I know how to implement the native smartbanner, but I would like to create one in javascript that:
- if the app is installed open the app
- else open play store

By browser i cant't know if the app is installed but amazon can do it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JS plugin to do that, like [jQuery Smart Banner](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner) or [Smart App Banner](https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner). It also works cross-browser/cross-os.

Comment: Hi lumio, I've already tried these plugins but they do not work because I always send them to the store, even if the user has already installed the app.